# Meaning of angles on Feynman diagram

Tags: radiation, feynman-diagrams

In physics class, I am currently studying Feynman diagrams. We are taught the basics like conservation of charge and the direction of time but the examples in my book all seem to follow specific paths (the gradients of the particle paths seem to remain the same in every textbook). Do the angles separating the particle paths and gradients of the lines mean anything or are all books just using the same images for simplicity?

In the image, the path of both the electron anti-neutrino and beta particle is always pointed in those specific directions.

[image]

Since the time axis points upwards I thought the angle/gradient would represent speed but my physics teacher thought otherwise.

Comment: @Jim delete that comment and post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Feynman diagrams is that they are rotatable and that they try to maintain a direction of progression of time. In this specific circumstance, it seems time flows from bottom to top. It indicates that the proton, electron, and neutrino are products, outputs from the interaction. If rotated, the inputs and outputs would change. In that way, the angling is important. But the specific angle is meaningless. The neutrino line could be shifted 20 degrees either way without changing the interpretation of the diagram.

Remember that the whole point of Feynman diagrams is to create a visual representation of an equation. Physicists want to be able to look at it and immediately be able to write down the corresponding equation. Thus, the angle of each line only matters insofar as you can tell the approximate region it's pointing in. Having to stop and directly measure angles would be counterproductive towards the ultimate goal of these diagrams.

Comment: Where did you go?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm still here, I just have no job. Without a job, I don't have the .... focus necessary to participate in this site. Not to worry, I'll be back full time before you know it

Comment: Understood. I got one of them job things and now I simply don't have the time to answer :(